# How do you catch unhandled exceptions in C# .net when the code is started by a COM call?

Tags: c#, com, unhandled-exception

How do you catch unhandled exceptions in C# .net when the code is started by a COM call?

I have tried to subscribe the unhandled exception event like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnhandledException);
```

But I think that code called from COM is loaded into the Process Address Space instead of the AppDomain.
So I guess the Current App Domain is not within the borders of my C# application but rather in the calling External EXE file (which is not in a .Net language).

I am trying to catch (and log) exceptions before reaching the calling EXE to provide better error information. Right now I just get a "Error calling external function".

**Update:** Please note that we use the event to catch HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute so adding more try/catch is not helping.

Comment: Why not just put try/catch at all of your entry points into c#?

Comment: Wpf? Winforms? ASP.net?  If win forms related, have you tried application.threadexception?  That will handle exceptions on the UI thread

Comment: @Derek There is 2 sides to this problem:
1. Catch exception that was missed because of the mistake of missing try/catch on the entry point.
2. Catching (logging) SEH and non-restartable exceptions like "AccessViloation".

Part 1 is fixable by having a "supervisor" person going in to review the code now and then to check if everyone is doing their job and adding try/catch.
Part 2 is not helped by try/catch since those exceptions is only "caught" by the AppDomain event.

Comment: @cdkMoose Sorry: None of those systems are used. Hans was right: we are calling it from PowerBuilder.

Comment: @HansPassant The entry point from PowerBuilder into C# creates a session object and then all access to the rest of the code goes through this. Can I somehow load the session class into an AppDomain and use that domain to catch exceptions?

Comment: Hard to decode, but yes, exceptions are caught by the CLR and translated to COM error codes.  As demanded by COM, a host like PowerBuilder doesn't know beans about .NET exceptions.  It also implements IErrorInfo so the host application can get a decent error message for the exception.  But your host is cr*pware, it does a very lousy job reporting errors.  It is very debuggable but if this happens in production then you have no clues.  All you could possibly do is put try/catch in every public method, log and rethrow in the catch clause.

Comment: @HansPassant But putting in Try/Catch everywhere is only half the story. We want to log exceptions that is handled by HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute in .Net. But since COM is in Process Address Space these goes to PowerBuilder and I want to log them in .Net (and then you have to kill the PB host anyway, which is ok since logging in Production is better than nothing).

Comment: You are asking for a pony.  Stop using Powerbuilder.

Comment: @HansPassant Hehe. The code is on a large system...

Comment: @HansPassant And of course: large system wide decisions is out of jurisdiction.